# What does a star * alone mean in a function declaration?

Tags: python, syntax, parameter-passing

What does the `*` mean in the following code (found in the `pprint` library)?

```
def pformat(object, indent=1, width=80, depth=None, *, compact=False):
    """Format a Python object into a pretty-printed representation."""
    return PrettyPrinter(indent=indent, width=width, depth=depth,
                         compact=compact).pformat(object)
```

If it was `*args` then it would be an arbitrary number of positional parameters. The parameter values would be in the tuple called `args`. The first 4 parameters could be assigned either by name or by position, the parameter `compact` could only be assigned by name...

Well, NO! Because it doesn't agree with [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

> In a function call, keyword arguments must follow positional
>   arguments.

So, what does the star do after and before other named arguments? And how is that used? Or why is it there if it is not used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It separates positional arguments from [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) when there are no variable arguments.  This is a Python-3-only feature.

Comment: Thanks. In the question I referred to the Python 2 documentation page, but the quoted phrase is also in the 3.